# Unlisting output from Bloomberg API (using blpAPI in R) using the 'lapply' function

Tags: r, lapply, bloomberg

I'm having trouble making my code dynamic using `lapply`. This is what I have:

```
library(Rblpapi)
blpConnect()
opt <- c("periodicitySelection"="QUARTERLY")
ovrd <- c("DS215" = "USD")

mylist1 <- bdh(c("MA EQUITY", "FB EQUITY","TSLA EQUITY"), c("IS010", 
"IS033"), start.date=Sys.Date()-365.25*1, options=opt, overrides=ovrd)
```

The output is:

```
$`MA EQUITY`
        date IS010 IS033
1 2016-12-31  2756  1363
2 2017-03-31  2734  1506
3 2017-06-30  3053  1653

$`FB EQUITY`
        date IS010 IS033

1 2016-12-31  8809  4566
2 2017-03-31  8032  3327
3 2017-06-30  9321  4401

$`TSLA EQUITY`
        date    IS010    IS033
1 2016-12-31 2284.631 -266.698
2 2017-03-31 2696.270 -257.549
3 2017-06-30 2789.557 -240.916
```

I can get what I want using `rbind`:

```
rbind(mylist1[[1]],mylist1[[2]],mylist1[[3]])
         date    IS010    IS033
 1 2016-12-31 2756.000 1363.000
 2 2017-03-31 2734.000 1506.000
 3 2017-06-30 3053.000 1653.000
 4 2016-12-31 8809.000 4566.000
 5 2017-03-31 8032.000 3327.000
 6 2017-06-30 9321.000 4401.000
 7 2016-12-31 2284.631 -266.698
 8 2017-03-31 2696.270 -257.549
 9 2017-06-30 2789.557 -240.916
```

Is there a way that I can use `lapply` to loop through when I have a larger data source? I've tried this:

```
lapply(mylist1, function(x) {rbind(as.data.frame(startDF),as.data.frame(x))})
```

But it doesn't work...

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Standard trick! `do.call(rbind, mylist1)`.

Comment: Thank you. really appreciate it! so easy

Comment: Quick question on this, the output appends a ".1", ".2" to each instance of the ticker. 

                    `MA EQUITY.1   

MA EQUITY.2 `

Is there a way to remove the appended values?

Comment: Yes, there is: `row.names(result) <- NULL`. This doesn't set the `row.names` to `NULL`, it renumbers them 1,... n.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, to clarify - I still would like to keep the tickers, just not the numbers. Is that possible? ideally: `MA EQUITY.1` becomes `MA EQUITY` .  I was thinking that `grep` would work....Thanks, again.

Comment: Row names must be unique. What you can do is to create a new column with the tickers. There are several ways of doing this. You can do `mylist1<-lapply(names(mylist1), function(x){mylist1[[x]]$ticker <- x;mylist1[[x]]})` before `do.call`.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help!